# Updating jQuery calendar event from a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar

I’m essentially trying to refresh the events on a jQuery calendar after a button is clicked, and a script updates the database.  The fist function is working but not the “add event”.

```
<script>
function quickevent(Value) {
$.post('submitvotime.php?Scope='+Value, 
$('form[name="VOQuickEntry"]').serialize(),
 function (output) {
    $('#info0').html(output).show();
    });
    }
</script>
<script>
function addevent(Value) {
$.post('event.php?Department=<?php echo $Department; ?>', 
 function (output) {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", html(output).show(); ); 
    });

    }
</script>
```

The initial calendar script is…

```
<script>

function MakeCalendar() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
if (allDay) {
    getday(date);
}
},


        defaultDate: <?php echo "'" . $DefaultDate . "'"; ?>,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
        <?php include 'events.php'; ?>

        ],
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        getevent(calEvent.id+';'+calEvent.type);

        }

    });

};

</script>
```

And the button is...

```
<input name="Button2" type="button" value="Office" onclick="quickevent('Office');addevent();">
```